# How to pass rgb color values to eventplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I'm simply trying to plot some tick marks with a specific color using matplotlib's eventplot. I'm running Python 3 in Jupyter notebook with %matplotlib inline.

Here's an example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
spikes = 100*np.random.random(100)
plt.eventplot(spikes, orientation='horizontal', linelengths=0.9, color=[0.3,0.3,0.5])
```

It outputs the following error:

```
ValueError: colors and positions are unequal sized sequences
```

The error occurs presumably because I am not providing a list of colors of the same length as the data (but I wan't them to all just be the same color!). It also gives an error when I use a color string like 'crimson' or 'orchid'. But it works when I use a simple one-letter string like 'r'.

Am I really restricted to just using the extremely limited set of one-letter color strings 'r','b','g','k','m','y', etc... or making a long color list when using this eventplot?

Comment: What do you expect to see when providing `color=[0.3,0.3,0.5]`? When you provide a list as a color parameter, matplotlib understands you want the first  event to be color[0], second to be color[1], ....

Comment: I want each tick mark to have the color defined by [0.3,0.3,0.5], which is a dark navy blue that I find easier on the eyes than the default 'b'. Do I really have to make a list of same length of data where each element is [0.3,0.3,0.5]?

Comment: No, you don't need that, try passing `color = (0.3,0.3,0.5)`, this way, as a tuple, that should work.

Comment: Are you sure? Did it work for you? Using a tuple still doesn't work for me :(

Comment: My bad, you should encapsulate that in a list aswell: `color = [(0.3,0.3,0.5)]`. Please let me know if that worked.

Comment: Well, now I tested this, it works!

Comment: Yes, thank you it works!

Comment: I'm glad to help, I posted it more complete as an answer, just remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it if it was helpful, it's an overall good for the community.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html):

> you can pass an (r, g, b) or (r, g, b, a) tuple, where each of r, g, b
>   and a are in the range [0,1].

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

spikes = 100*np.random.random(100)
plt.eventplot(spikes, orientation='horizontal', linelengths=0.9, color = [(0.3,0.3,0.5)])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Heads up for anyone trying this color syntax for the `.plot` function. In that case, drop the list of the tuple, but just give a tuple of RGB values.

Answer (score 1):

```
# for a list of three plotted variables

df = data[['x', 'y', 'z']]
color_theme=[(52/235, 235/235, 86/235), (52/235, 70/235, 235/235), 
(165/235, 52/235, 235/235)]           
df.plot(color=color_theme)

# where numerators are the R,G,B numbers
# python only uses RGB in numbers <1
# denominator is obviously the max RGB quantity on a normal RGB scale
```

Comment: I do believe that the max RGB quantity is, actually, 256, since it is a range between 0 and 255